# Kubernetes node affinity prefer node with highest value

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm aware that I can use [k8s node affinity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/update-existing-nodepools) to select for nodes that have a value of a label `gt` than some value. However is it possible to make k8s prefer to schedule on nodes that have the *greatest* value? I.e. if one node has `schedule-on-me: 5` and another has `schedule-on-me: 6` it will prefer to schedule on the one with the higher value?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. You can tune weights in the scheduler but I don't think any those would help here so would need a custom scheduler extender webhook.